# Match each using Examples from Scenario Outline

Tags: karate

I find using `* match each response.xyz` super powerful for merging object structure testing with content testing. Is there a way to use it with `Examples` tables and `<placeholder>`?

I've got something like this, that I want to use an Examples table on:

```
    * match each response.Services ==
  """
  { 
    "ServiceId" : #present, 
    "Name" : <Name>, 
    "Description" : #present, 
    "InActive" : <Inactive>, 
  }
  """
    Examples: 
  | ClientId | Name       | Status | ErrorCode | Inactive |
  |   400152 | "Foxtrot"  |    200 |         0 | false    |
  |   400152 | "Waltz"    |    200 |         0 | false    |
```

I get

```
  "Services": [
{
  "ServiceId": 3,
  "Name": "Waltz",
  "Description": "Waltzing like Matilda",
  "InActive": false,
},
{
  "ServiceId": 4,
  "Name": "Foxtrot",
  "Description": "",
  "InActive": false,
},
```

back as a response.
Obviously, when I'm using multiple lines in `Examples:`, it results in several tests.

What I'm looking for is to test each object in the array against predefined values, but without knowing what order they'll show up in. And use the ordered approach like tables produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `each`, try this:

```
* match response.Services contains
  """
  { 
    "ServiceId" : #present, 
    "Name" : <Name>, 
    "Description" : #present, 
    "InActive" : <Inactive>, 
  }
  """
```

EDIT: okay, an alternate option. By the way there are at least 5 different ways I can think of :P

```
Scenario:
* table data
  | ClientId | Name       | Status | ErrorCode | Inactive |
  |   400152 | "Foxtrot"  |    200 |         0 | false    |
  |   400152 | "Waltz"    |    200 |         0 | false    |
* def expected = karate.map(data, function(x){ return { ServiceId: '#present', Name: x.Name, Description: '#present', InActive: x.Inactive} })
* match response.Services contains expected
```

EDIT2: if you can control the whole `table`:

```
Scenario:
* table expected
| Name       | InActive | ServiceId  | Description |
| "Foxtrot"  | false    | '#present' | '#present'  |
| "Waltz"    | false    | '#present' | '#present'  |
* match response.Services contains expected
```

Comment: That's how i use it currently, but it forces me to call the same function several times for each possible object in the return array. I find it not so pretty with the redundant data in the Examples table :)

Comment: Interesting. If it scans through the entire data table and matches the objects in the array, in one go, that would be pretty cool solution. Unfortunately I get  at ✽.* def expected = karate.map(data, function(x){ return { Name: x.Name, InActive: x.Inactive} })(single/GetServices.feature:68)
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: karate.map is not a function in <eval> at line number 1 in my cut down test.

Comment: upgrade to 0.8.0 pls :)

Comment: That's just evil, although I do understand the desire to publish solutions for current builds. My horse is stuck on 0.7.0 till the end of this project. Am I completely out of luck? Can always call the added function calls "embedded performance testing".

Comment: I hope you get eternal life.. This is exactly what I was looking for. I've verified that all lines in the table are tested even with contains, using == and changing the order of the rows. And it integrates well with Examples tables for multiple test cases.